# How do I prevent RDoc from parsing a URL?

Tags: ruby, rdoc

Assume that I have the follow class.

```
class Foo

  # I want the following to appear as-is in my documentation, not as an anchor tag. 
  #
  # http://www.google.com/
  #
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

And then I run it through rdoc.

`$ rdoc foo.rb`

It generates this:

```
<div class="method-description">
  <p>
    I want the following to appear as-is in my documentation, not as an anchor tag.
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="http://www.google.com">www.google.com</a>/
  </p>
</div>
```

I want it to generate something like this instead:

```
<div class="method-description">
  <p>
    I want the following to appear as-is in my documentation, not as an anchor tag.
  </p>
  <p>
    http://www.google.com/
  </p>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1**

Make sure that you're using:

```
ruby 1.9.2
rdoc 2.5.8
```

**Step 2**

Escape it and you should be fine.

```
class Foo

  # I want the following to appear as-is in my documentation, not as an anchor tag. 
  #
  # \http://www.google.com/
  #
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

Output:

```
<div class="method-description"> 
  <p>
    I want the following to appear as-is in my documentation, not as an anchor tag.
  </p>  
  <p>
    http://www.google.com/
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really the output that you got? All this produces for me is a backslash in front of the anchor tag.

Comment: Yep, that's it. http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3476/outputf.png Sorry for the low sized screenshot.

Comment: Interesting. Which versions of ruby and rdoc are you using?

Comment: It was a version problem. I was trying to use an older ruby / rdoc. I'm assuming that only the rdoc version actually matters, but I updated the answer to include both versions used.