# Stop Rdoc from creating link on a string

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I'm using RDoc for the first time, and I've run into one issue that's a bit bothersome. I have a line in my class documentation like the following:

```
# * callingState
```

I also have a class in that same project called State. When I generate the documentation for my project using RDoc, it links the "State" part of the line above to my State object.

I'd prefer to not have it behave this way. Is there any way to stop this link from being automatically created by RDoc? A quick Google search hasn't yielded any results, but I may just be searching using the wrong terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this specific case happen.  I tried to reproduce it, but the links were not created when only part of a word matches a class.  I do, however, have plenty of occurrences where I don't want to link to a class or module name.  Prepending a backslash to the capitalized word did the trick for me.

See:
[How do I prevent RDoc from parsing a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676167/how-do-i-prevent-rdoc-from-parsing-a-url)

Answer (score 0):

RDoc documentation has a section about [Escaping Text Markup](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/RDoc/Markup.html#class-RDoc::Markup-label-Escaping+Text+Markup), which helped me.

```
* This will not be linked to \RDoc::RDoc#document
```